# Labyrinth recognition is slow and recognition is not always acurate

Tags: python, opencv

I'm making a Python script that:

1. gets the image from file
2. Looks for a papersheet (done by openCV)
3. Warps the image
4. crops the margins of papersheet
5. Looks for lowest amount of white pixels in a single row of pixels which makes up for width/height of a single field of a grid (goes pixel by pixel)
6. Recreates the labyrinth based on what are the average pixel RGB Values in each field (goes pixel by pixel) and saves it to file
7. It shows me the grid of 0 and 1s in the CLI

When I do it on original image (5.2MB, 4000x3000) , it takes up to 20 seconds (although I have pretty snappy 8 core ryzen cpu), actually I only need the output (0 or 1 grid). How can I speed up the process as it will run on raspberry pi and it needs to take only about few seconds to finish? I know that the code is quite long, however it's split into sections that are described so it should be fairly easy to read.

```
#LIBRARY IMPORT
import math
import turtle                   
import time
import sys
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
from skimage import exposure
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

#LOAD THE FIRST IMAGE
image = cv2.imread("./image3.jpg")
ratio = image.shape[0] / 600.0
orig = image.copy()
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 600)

#Range of the colors of paper
lower = [160, 160, 160]
upper = [255,255,255]

#create array from ranges
lower = np.array(lower, dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array(upper, dtype="uint8")

#finding contours
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask, 40, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
cnt = contours
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
for c in [contours]:

#contour approximation
   peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
   approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.01 * peri, True)

#crop of contour with 4 points
   if len(approx) == 4:
      screenCnt = approx
      break
img = cv2.drawContours(image,[screenCnt],0,(0,0,255),2)
print(screenCnt)
pts = screenCnt.reshape(4, 2)
rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype = "float32")
s = pts.sum(axis = 1)
rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]
diff = np.diff(pts, axis = 1)
rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)]
rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]
rect *= ratio
(tl, tr, br, bl) = rect
widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))
maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))
dst = np.array([
   [0, 0],
   [maxWidth - 1, 0],
   [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
   [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
warp = cv2.warpPerspective(orig, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))
warp = imutils.resize(warp)
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.moveWindow("image",0,450)
cv2.imwrite("warp.jpg",warp)

#warping of found labyrinth
warp = cv2.imread("warp.jpg",0)
warp = cv2.medianBlur(warp,5)
ret,warp = cv2.threshold(warp,170,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite("warp.jpg",warp)
image_file = "warp.jpg"
im = Image.open(image_file)
width, height = im.size
T = height*(5/210)
B = height-(height*(5/210))
L = width*(5/210)
R = width-(width*(5/210))
im_crop = im.crop((L, T, R, B))
im=im_crop
im_crop.save('warp.png', quality=100)
white=0

#finding field-size 
im = Image.open("warp.png")
width, height = im.size
minimalGridWidth2 = width
minimalGridWidth = width
MaximumGridWidth = width
for y in range (0, height):
   for x in range (0, width):
      if im.getpixel((x,y)) > 200:
         white = white+1
   if white <= minimalGridWidth:
      minimalGridWidth = white

#checks out how many X how many fields the labirynt has, checks what's the average value (more black or more white) is there on that field and recreates the new "ideal" labyrinth from this data
gridWidth = int(round(width/minimalGridWidth))
gridHeight = int(round(height/minimalGridWidth))
print(gridWidth)|
print(gridHeight)
newHeight = 0
newWidth = 0
newHeight=(minimalGridWidth*gridHeight)
newWidth=(minimalGridWidth*gridWidth)
print(minimalGridWidth)
print(newWidth)
print(newHeight)
im = im.resize((newWidth, newHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
i=0
x, y = gridWidth, gridHeight
pixelcount = [[0 for x in range(0,gridWidth)] for y in range(0,gridHeight)]
pixelavg = [[0 for x in range(0,gridWidth)] for y in range(0,gridHeight)]
print(pixelcount)
for y in range (0, gridHeight):
   for x in range (0, gridWidth):
      i=0
      pixel=0
      for v in range (0, minimalGridWidth):
         for w in range (0, minimalGridWidth):
            pixel=pixel+im.getpixel((((x*minimalGridWidth)+w),((y*minimalGridWidth)+v)))
            i=i+1
      if (pixel/i)<127:
         pixelavg[y][x]=1
      elif (pixel/i)>127:
         pixelavg[y][x]=0
print(np.array(pixelavg))
y,x,v,w,i=0,0,0,0,0
im2 = Image.new('RGB',(newWidth,newHeight),'white')
for y in range (0, gridHeight):
   for x in range (0, gridWidth):
      for v in range (0, minimalGridWidth):
         for w in range (0, minimalGridWidth):
            pixelx=pixelavg[y][x]
               if pixelx==0:
                  pixelDoc=(255,255,255)
               if pixelx==1:
                  pixelDoc=(0,0,0)
               Xw=((x*minimalGridWidth)+w)
               Yh=((y*minimalGridWidth)+v)
               im2.putpixel((Xw,Yh),pixelDoc) 
im2.save('warp3.png',quality=100)
imx=cv2.imread('warp3.png',0)
cv2.imshow('finito',imx)
cv2.imwrite('koniec.png',imx)
cv2.moveWindow("finito",750,450)
warp=cv2.imread("warp.png",0)
cv2.imshow("warp",warp)
cv2.moveWindow("warp",450,450)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are concerned with performance or looking to optimize code, it can help to profile your program.
You could use [Python's profiler](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/profile.html) or an IDE with a profiler like PyCharm.
When profiling your code on a 4000x2665 image, I found the following:

[image]

As you can see, the `getpixel` and `putpixel` functions take ~60% of the total execution time.
This makes sense, as they are called for every image pixel in a nested loop:

```
for y in range (0, height):
   white = 0
   for x in range (0, width):
      if im.getpixel((x,y)) > 200:
         white = white+1
   if white <= minimalGridWidth:
      minimalGridWidth = white
```

The above code can be fixed by replacing the nested loops by image-wide operations.

```
np_im = np.array(im)
white_per_row = np.sum(np_im > 200, axis=1)
minimalGridWidth = np.min(white_per_row)
```

Replacing this single operation cuts down the total execution time by 5644 ms or ~32%

[image]

Comment: But this whole loop goes like this:
for y in range (0, height):
 for x in range (0, width):
  if im.getpixel((x,y)) > 200:
   white = white+1
 if white <= minimalGridWidth:
  minimalGridWidth = white
As it checks in every row and if the current row has the lowest amount of white pixels then it changes the minimalGridWidth to white and I assume yours only sums all white pixels on the image

Comment: Good point, I missed that part. I changed that part of the answer.